# How to persist HKQueryAnchor in remote server

Tags: swift, healthkit

I know it's possible to persist HKQueryAnchor on the device, but is it possible to persist it in some ways in a remote server?

More specifically, I don't know the internal structure of HKQueryAnchor class so I don't know how to turn it into a Json to send to the server.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialize `HKQueryAnchor` as `NSData` using `NSKeyedArchiver` and store the byte contents of the `NSData` on the server. This is the same approach you would use to persist the anchor locally on the device (in user defaults, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Took me a little digging to find the exact code to follow @Allan's suggestion so I'll leave it here in case it's helpful to anyone.

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: anchor)
String encoded = data.base64EncodedString()
```